# Is there any way to download sites from Google Site?

Tags: html, google-sites

I created a site using [sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com). Now I want to download it to publish. Is there any way that the site can be downloaded?

Comment: `curl` or `wget` presumsbly.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can get a hold of some basic content using HTTrack or equivalent, you don't need to download the website in order to publish it. Google Sites will publish the site for you, ([instructions](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/6372880?hl=en)) from within the Google Sites editor.

The site can even [use your own domain name if you have one](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=en&ref_topic=6372882). The instructions assume a personal Google account, there is a slightly different process for a G-Suite for Business Account.

Comment: Yeah but it is slow to publish the first time. Lot faster to self-host (for those who have the option and are impatient enough)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can download a complete site or just a bunch of pages with every separate file.

A windows application called **HTTrack** makes it possible to download whole site with all separate files.

1. Download HTTrack from [here](https://www.httrack.com/page/2/).
2. Open it and type the url or site domain to wich you want to copy.
3. Choose the folder where you want to save it.
4. And run the process, make sure you have stable internet connection.
5. The process will be finish as it's total file size.

Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-download-an-entire-Google-Site-hosted-on-Google-Sites-and-use-it-for-offline-viewing-or-hosting-it-on-a-local-server)

Comment: Problem is when you download site (sites.google.com) it redirects. It does not allow a user to edit offline in any means.

Comment: My problem is my site is private, and I cannot seem to pass it my username and password, or at least it does not seem to work when I follow the instructions provided in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For unix people:

`wget -e robots=off -m -k -K -E -rH -Dsites.google.com http://sites.google.com/a/domain/site/`

Where the options recursively download the sites. Specifically, the [`wget` options stand for...](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html)

- `-e robots=off`: Ignore robots.txt instruction from site
- `-m`: Turn on options suitable for mirroring
- `-k`: After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing
- `-K`: When converting a file, back up the original version with a `.orig` suffix
- `-E`: If a file of type `application/xhtml+xml` or `text/html` is downloaded and the URL does not end with the regexp `\.[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]?`, this option will cause the suffix `.html` to be appended to the local filename
- `-r`: Turn on recursive retrieving.
- `H`: Enable spanning across hosts when doing recursive retrieving.
- `-Dsites.google.com`: Set the domain to be followed.

And if you're using windows, you could [try getting `wget` for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74709129/1175496)

Answer (score 1):

HTTrack or any equivalent is really old techniques, and sometimes the website downloaded by these 3rd party software, won't work properly.

With a better approach, Google Takeout is the best option.
I am here attaching few links, how to download google sites as .zip to your local computer.
[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mSvveupZa0) and
[Blog for reference](https://www.steegle.com/google-sites/how-to/export-with-takeout)