# wget command not found in git bash

Tags: path, wget, git-bash

I've already tried pip install wget in my cmd, which reads

```
>pip install wget
Requirement already satisfied: wget in c:\users\user\...\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (3.2)
```

however when I try the command in git bash, it keeps showing

```
$ wget
bash: wget: command not found
```

I've made sure both the python file and the git file are in PATH.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe time has come for you to try Linux ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the command:

```
pip install wget
```

you installed this Python library https://pypi.org/project/wget/, so you can use that from inside Python:

```
import wget
```

---

I imagine what you actually want is to be able to use `wget` from inside Git bash. To do what, install [Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and add the executable to the path. Or, alternatively, use `curl`.

Answer (score 13):

If you would like to use `curl` on `Git Bash`, here is an example:

```
$ curl -kLSs https://github.com/opscode/chef-repo/tarball/master -o master.tar.gz
  
$ ls master.tar.gz
master.tar.gz
```

- `-L` follow redirects
- `-o` (lower case O) to write output to file instead of stdout.
- `Ss` silent mode, but show errors, if any
- `k` allows curl to proceed and operate even for server connections otherwise considered insecure.

Reference: [curl](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) manpage.

Answer (score 8):

if you are just looking for having wget in the git bash without pip or any other dependency, you can follow the nice and quick tutorial from this page:

[How to add more to Git Bash on Windows](https://gist.github.com/evanwill/0207876c3243bbb6863e65ec5dc3f058)

the essence of it is:

1. Download wget binaries for Windows here (preferrably as ZIP) [eternallybored](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)
2. extract the wget.exe from the zip
3. copy the EXE file to your git bash binaries folder e.g. "c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin"

done :)

Answer (score -4):

To have the `wget` command in the gitbash shell, Quick and dirty replacement for the single argument, fetch a file usecase:

```
alias wget='curl -O'
```

> `-O, --remote-name   Write output to a file named as the remote file`

Maybe give the alias a different name so you don't try to use wget flags in curl.

This has nothing to do with the shell package.